# nova conductor and scheduler not starting

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

Another question which I think is related to my previous question:

When I do:

```
nova service-list
nova-conductor and scheduler seems to be enabled, but status is down.
```

How can I start these services.? I tried:

```
service nova-compute restart
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart nova-compute.service
Failed to restart nova-compute.service: Unit not found.
```

I have port 5672 opened, and is a single host deployment (node, controller etc reside in the same physical host). Can someone help me at the earliest please.?